# I am trying to use the public variable in another scipt in PHP, but im getting two errors

Tags: php

**Config.php**

```
 <?php 
    //Database Connection constants         
    define('DB_HOST' , 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER' , 'root');
    define('DB_PASS' , '');
    define('DB_NAME' , 'gallery_db');
?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once ("config.php");

     class Database {

        public $connection;

        function __construct() {

        $this->open_db_connection();
        } 
        public function open_db_connection () {

        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("database connection failed badly" . mysqli_error());
        }        
        }        
    }

    // $database = new Database();
    $database = new Database();    

?>
```

### init.php

```
 <?php       
     include "config.php";
     include "database.php";        
 ?>
```

### admin_content.php

```
     <div id="page-wrapper">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- Page Heading -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h1 class="page-header">
                                Blank Page
                                <small>Subheading</small>
                            </h1>
                        <?php 


                            if($database->connection) // the line that the error is pointing to
                            {
                                echo "true";
                            }
                        ?>

                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li>
                                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="active">
                                    <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Blank Page
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->

                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
```

the code is working fine on the same file, but following (2) erors are there when i try to access the public variable from a different file/scipt

### errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: database in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\admin_content.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\admin\includes\admin_content.php on line 15

Comment: include 'init.php'; in your admin_content.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**init.php**

```
<?php       
     include "config.php";
     include "database.php";        
 ?>
```

**edit (init.php)**

```
<?php       
 include "config.php";
 include "Database.php";        
?>
```

**admin_content.php**

```
//include init.php file
<?php include 'init.php' ?>
<div id="page-wrapper">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- Page Heading -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h1 class="page-header">
                                Blank Page
                                <small>Subheading</small>
                            </h1>
                        <?php 


                            if($database->connection) // the line that the error is pointing to
                            {
                                echo "true";
                            }
                        ?>

                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li>
                                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="active">
                                    <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Blank Page
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->

                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
```

**result**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `init.php` file in `admin_content.php`

Write below line in top of your `admin_content.php` file

```
<?php include 'init.php'; ?>
```

**Note:-** You do not need to include  `config.php` file in your `init.php` file because that file is already loaded in `database.php` file.